# objcopy failed on makefile but no problem on typing it manually in Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, virtual-machine

I have this Makefile with the following commands:

```
all:
    gcc -MD -fno-builtin -nostdinc -fno-stack-protector -Os -g -m32 -I. -c -o boot0.o boot0.S
    ld -nostdlib -m elf_i386 -N -e start -Ttext 0x7c00 -o boot0.elf boot0.o
    objcopy -S -O binary boot0.elf boot0
    ....
```

While these commands are pre-written and I just copy and paste into the makefile, while I do

```
make all
```

in the terminal, it will return

```
make: objcopy: command not found
```

This is impossible considering I am running Xubuntu via VMBox. But later on I found out that if I manually type that command it will work. But it won't work if I copy and paste the command into the terminal. Even if I did paste it I need to re-type `objcopy` in order to make it work. But this trick does not work on the makefile. Also it happens on `gcc` and `ld`, but both of them eventually worked when I re-typed the command in makefile but not `objcopy`. What is the problem in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But later on I found out that if I manually type that command it will
>   work. But it won't work if I copy and paste the command into the
>   terminal. Even if I did paste it I need to re-type objcopy in order to
>   make it work.

If copying and pasting the command into a terminal window doesn't work, but manually (re)typing the command into the same terminal window does work, then it follows that you're not actually entering the same command.

> Also it happens on gcc and ld, but both of them eventually worked when
>   I re-typed the command in makefile but not objcopy.

That pretty much nails it for me.  Your makefile very likely contains non-printing characters that Ubuntu does not recognize as whitespace.  At least one such character being immediately adjacent to each command name, probably immediately preceding it, the command name is interpreted as including that character.  Moreover, you can cut & paste that along with the command, but of course it's not there if you just type what appears to be the command in the makefile.

Sometimes one sees a similar problem related to having Windows line terminators instead of Unix line terminators, but that does not appear to be the case here.  I speculate that it may have originated from copying the makefile content from a web page.

You can filter all such characters from your makefile by processing it with [the `tr` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr):

```
tr -cd '\t\n\040-\176' < Makefile > Makefile.new
```

That keeps tabs, newlines, and ASCII characters from code 040 through 176 octal (== 32 - 126 decimal == 20 - 7e hex).  You'll be able to tell whether it changed anything by comparing the sizes of the original and new files.  Supposing that the new file is smaller and looks ok, go ahead and replace the original.